# Weird behavior with selectAllOnFocus when EditText is in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, focus, android-edittext

This problem has been bugging me for a while now. I have a list view and in each row there are three EditText in which user can enter data. When a user selects an edit box, the text should be selected, so when he types the first key, the previous text is removed.

This all works perfectly with selectAllOnFocus option set to true. The problem occurs when I have to call notifyDataSetChanged. There is a button in each row that deletes the row and that is when I call the notifyDataSetChanged method of the adapter. After this, when a user selects an EditBox, it doesn't selects the whole text, but the cursor sets to the left side of the text and an arrow is displayed below the cursor.

I tried setting selectAllOnFocus in code and in layout file, but no luck.

What should I try? Am I missing something?

I tried with disabling the focus changed event, no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was happening whenever I call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), I figured I should try to go around it. And this is what I ended up doing:

```
adapter.clear();     
adapter = new AdapterOfWhateverItemsTypeIs(this, items);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);   
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

After this, I got the expected behavior of selectAllOnFocus option of EditText.

Answer (score 0):

What is the expected behavior your trying to achieve?

EDIT:

Why not try firing off a two click events manually. Its a slightly hacky solution but if it works than who cares. What you can do is get the view from your list view that you want to have the text selected in and fire off the two clicks in a post like so

```
myEdit.post(new Runnable(){

    public void run() 
  {
    myEdit.performClick();
    myEdit.performClick();
  }

}
```

using the post would make sure that the events got fired after the view had been re-inflated after calling invalidate on your listview adapter

Comment: Read the question carefully :)
When the user selects an EditText, the whole text is selected and the keyboard pops up. This is what I want, but it doesn't work like that always. Sometimes (usually after the keyboard is visible) when the user selects a different EditText, it doesn't select (highlight) the whole text, but it just focuses on the leftmost side of the control and an arrow is displayed below the cursor.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, please edit the question if you think you can improve it. And let me know if you need some more details. Thanks

Comment: So you want the cursor to be positioned to the end of the text?

Comment: No, I want the whole text in the EditText to be selected (highlighted) when the keyboard appears and whenever the user changes focus in another EditText. What I've noticed is that this is working fine up until I call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter.

Comment: I found a solution. Check out my answer and let me know if something can be wrong with it. It is working, though :)